# How to disable year selection on element-ui date/week etc. picker?

Tags: element-ui

I am trying to disable year selection on element-ui in vue js and I am using the week selector, tried couple of options but no solution could be found. Its not included in documentation as well, would appreciate if someone could help me out.

```
 <el-date-picker
                    v-model="week"
                    type="week"
                    format="WW"
                    placeholder="Select Week"
                    @change="weekChanged" :picker-options="options">
            </el-date-picker>
```

Currently I have this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KAc5p.jpg

I would like to disable the highlighted arrows which is for year selection. Just want to display the current year only. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done through css if it justifies your question.

```
.el-icon-d-arrow-left,.el-icon-d-arrow-right{
  display: none;
}
```

**NOTE** Here, **.el-icon-d-arrow-left** and **.el-icon-d-arrow-right** are the left and right arrow buttons for selecting year in el-date-picker dialog.